# PLSQL PIVOT with string as the aggregated value. Error "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: plsql, pivot

I'm getting an issue with PIVOT. I want to pivot where the aggregated value is a string. Technically it doesn't actually need aggregated as there will only ever be one value per cell. I'm pivoting so that there is a column per question, with the answers in the columns below.

Code:

```
    SELECT  EFOLDERID,
            SUN,
            LEGALNAME,
            QLIST_NAME
    FROM    V_CCRA_EXPORT_ANSWERS
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(DERIVED_ANSWER) -- we have to use an aggregate function here, but (a) it's a string and (b) there will only ever be one value per cell, so MAXing it works fine (as would AVG or MIN)
        FOR QUESTION_NUMBER
        IN  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
    );
```

I'm getting the error:
`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB`,
`00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

DERIVED_ANSWER is defined in the view, but the field is cast to a VARCHAR(1000) within the view.

Can I use PIVOT like this? Thanks. I'm unclear what the error message is telling me is wrong.

**UPDATE (1):**
For info, QUESTION_NUMBER is VARCHAR(20). I've modified the SQL to:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    V_CCRA_EXPORT_ANSWERS
PIVOT
(
    MAX(DERIVED_ANSWER) -- we have to use an aggregate function here, but (a) it's a string and (b) there will only ever be one value per cell, so MAXing it works fine (as would AVG or MIN)
    FOR (QUESTION_NUMBER)
    IN  ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12')
);
```

This still returns the same error.

**UPDATE (2)**:  Figured this out. Short-sweet answer is: Don't include an `NCLOB` in the input `SELECT` for a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, found the answer to this. One of the columns within `V_CCRA_EXPORT_ANSWERS` is an `NCLOB`. It appears that you can't use an `NCLOB` column in the `SELECT` that feeds into a `PIVOT`, irrespective of whether you use it in the `PIVOT` or not. I've updated the query so that there is a sub-select only selects the columns I specifically want for the `PIVOT` and it doesn't include the NCLOB column, thus:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  SUN,
                    LEGALNAME,
                    EFOLDERID,
                    CREATED_DATE,
                    QLIST_NAME,
                    QUESTION_NUMBER,
                    DERIVED_ANSWER
            FROM    V_CCRA_EXPORT_ANSWERS
        )
PIVOT
(
    MAX(DERIVED_ANSWER) -- we have to use an aggregate function here, but (a) it's a string and (b) there will only ever be one value per cell, so MAXing it works fine (as would AVG or MIN)
    FOR (QUESTION_NUMBER)
    IN  ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12')
)
ORDER BY SUN,
        CREATED_DATE;
```

It now works as expected.

TL;DR : Don't include an `NCLOB` in the input `SELECT` for a `PIVOT`.